# PostgreSQL using NO_DATA_FOUND exception in a sored Procedure

Tags: postgresql, exception

When I try to run a PostgreSQL stored procedure including the "STRICT" option and a record variable (rec) as I try to save (run the create statement) I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "rec"
LINE 14:  INTO STRICT rec
```

I' am following the guidelines stated on the official documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW
where the only reference missing is that this can or can't be used inside a function or a stored procedure. I guess there should be a reasonable answer to this issue I couldn't found. I was able to succeed running an equivalent code inside a Do block, so it seams there is some incompatibility declaring a record type variable and functions.
This is the function code I was running:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_nodata()
RETURNS TABLE(id int, active boolean)

 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$

DECLARE
 rec record;
 tab VARCHAR ='text_maintenance_news';

    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT tm.id, tm.active
        INTO STRICT rec
        FROM text_maintenance_news tm
        WHERE tm.active
        LIMIT 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE 'Query from % has no data', tab; 
END;
$$
```

As mentioned at the official documents, postgreSQL doesn't consider no data as an error but as a warning that the programmer must handle. Main reason to include the STRICT option.

Do block code (It works!) and result:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    tab varchar = 'text_maintenance_news';
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO STRICT rec
    FROM text_maintenance_news
    WHERE active
    LIMIT 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE 'Query from % return no data', tab;
END;
$$

ERROR:  Query from text_maintenance_news return no data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at RAISE
SQL state: P0001
```

Comment: If you use `return  query` then using `into strict` makes no sense. `return query` will return the result of the query (hence the name). There is no need to store that result anywhere. Of _if_ you want to store the result in a row, then get rid of the `return query` (as you did in the DO block)

Comment: As the docs show [Return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) *43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY*  `RETURN QUERY` has no provision for `SELECT INTO ...`, because as @a_horse_with_no_name commented it makes no sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; @Adrian. You guys were right. Removing the RETURN QUERY line solves the issue. But now I wonder, what it'll be de use of a no data exception when your function won't return a sensible result but when there is no data

Comment: `FOUND` works with `RETURN QUERY` per [Diagnostics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).